# How to iterate over JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have my json response in the form of array like this

```
name:{'bob','martin','jame'}
```

I am using for each loop for this but unable to get values

```
$.each( response, function( key, value ) {
 alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: is this the actual response?is it a correct json?

Comment: by looking at your response we can say its an invalid. It would have been valid if it looks something like : `name:['bob','martin','jame']`. That is `name` key is holding a string array.

Comment: Edited my question.. i just forgot to put ' '

Comment: still your JSON is invalid. `{ ... }` means javascript object which will have again `key:value` format. But in your case there are only strings separated by comma. Please correct it. Please modify your server side code to get you correct format on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Still doubtful over your JSON response representation but still following answer might be helpful.

Provide your json response to a variable as follows:

```
var jsonResp = {"name":[{"bob","martin","jame"}]};
```

Then you can use `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<jsonResp.name.length; i++){
     var key,value;
     jsonResp.name.map(function(nameObj){        
     for (key in nameObj) {
        value = (nameObj[key] == '')?'none': nameObj[key];
        alert(key +":"+ value);
    }
    });  
}
```